# Replacement for Opalis Robot3

Tags: automation, information-management, scheduling

Working at a co. with an old server running Opalis Robot 3, an early 2000's era scheduling & orchestration engine.  Basically it schedules a bunch of tasks that happen within the enterprise like "run this batch-file, which is a sql script, against a database, and email the results to phb@office.front".  It's a pain in the arse to manage because the application doesn't include any search/discovery features, it's just got everything placed in folders/trees based on the whims whoever set it up at the time.

MS bought Opalis in 2009, and slowly over time integrated their products into System Center.  There's also these two interesting MS "Open Source" projects:

http://opalis.codeplex.com/

http://orchestrator.codeplex.com/

But I can't find any info on what the "community editions" mean or how they're limited, vs. a full enterprise cost product.

So my question is 2-part:

1. Short of a complete audit & re-construction of the entire catalog of jobs, does anyone have any recommendations for an upgrade path that could save us some headache?
2. If we need to go that route (audit, re-construct from scratch) -- which is fine, frankly, because there are probably several jobs that can be purged anyway -- what software would you recommend?

So far, besides the 2 above, I've seen stuff like this:

http://www.helpsystems.com/skybot

http://www.advsyscon.com/en-us/activebatch/it-automation-without-boundaries.aspx

http://www.jamsscheduler.com/

Any ideas from you brilliant people?  (And yes, IT Infrastructure stack is primary MS/Windows based.)